# Select box text is going top in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I have a HTML code below.

```
<div style="height:300px; width:300px; background:#000 ">
 <div style="padding:30px">
   <select id="keywordsearch" class="upperslect">
       <option value="1">ABC</option>
       <option value="2" >Def</option>
       <option value="3" selected="selected">Select Box</option>
       <option value="4">GGGG</option>  
    </select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And the following CSS is

```
.upperslect 
{ 
    font-family:Tahoma; 
    color:#6C6C6C;
    border: none; 
    background:#FFFFFF; 
    font-family:Arial; 
    font-size:12px; 
    width:155px; 
    height:26px;
    margin:0px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

 }
```

But I am getting strange output on all two browsers(Mozilla, Chrome). See the images below.

[image]
Chrome Picture

[image]
Mozilla Firefox Picture

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem. The chrome picture is right actually. I also tried padding but with padding the select box array is going down.

Besides that I am trying to put a background image on the Select box but I am unable to

Answer (score 1):

Some padding on the select and also adjusting the select height to compensate for the padding should do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/pYg8v/

Comment: IS there any way to add a background image on select box? I am unable to do that